# Import an excel file as a resource in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I'm new with Talend. I've got an excel file with header rows and filters. My job copies this file into a working directory (`tFile_copy`) and then fills the file with data selected from a database. Then it sends the result file by mail.

Everything works, but I would like to store my "template" excel file into my Talend project in order to put it into svn and find it easily when another person will need this job again in a few months.

The "import item" menu doesn't allow .xls files. Is there a clean way to import resource files into a Talend project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Metadata with your template excel. Metadatas can be imported or exported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the CONTEXTS feature to solve this issue? http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=34

Comment: I use context as in this tutorial, but in this example it stores a file path **outside** the project (`C:/Users/...`); what I want is to store my file **inside** my Talend project.